# How to distort a grid object into a tapered shape, like a trash basket icon?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, distort

I want to do this:

[image]

**The bin just above**

I think this tool is well designed for this purpose :
[image]

But after few hours of trying, i still don't know how I can tighten the bottom to make it look like a bin :
[image]

I guess there are many ways to achieve this, how would one go to easily do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just after making this grid shape select and go to <kbd>Effect menu</kbd> in Adobe Illustrator 
Go to <kbd>Effect -- Distort -- Free Distort</kbd> and drag the two below points to give it a shape of BIN as shown in image below.
[image]

Press <kbd>OK</kbd> to give this shape 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple possibilities that come to mind:

#### Using Free Distort

1. select your object;
2. choose <kbd>Effect > Distort & Transform > Free Distort...</kbd>;
3. using the anchors in the dialog, change the shape of the preview until you're satisfied;
4. click <kbd>Ok</kbd>;
5. <kbd>Object > Expand Appearance</kbd> to taste.

#### Using an Envelope distort

1. using any tool, draw a (closed) shape you want your grid to be in;
2. select both the grid and the shape;
3. choose <kbd>Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Top Object</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl/Option</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>);
4. <kbd>Object > Expand Appearance</kbd> to taste.